# trying to scan a float into a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c, pointers

i have a struct similar to so:

```
struct Node
{
    char itemName[256];
    int idNumber;
    float price;
    struct Node * next;
}; typedef struct Node node
```

i'm trying to scan user input from console into the price element of the node, like so:

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

scanf("%d", &(new_node->idNumber));
scanf("%f", &(new_node->price));
```

i am trying to print the statement with:

```
printf("%f", new_node->price);
```

i have some other methods that perform a calculation with this value, and they are not outputting the correct values.  so i started trying to print what was stored in that price element.. if i input something like 32.40, it will only print 0.40.  am i missing something?

Comment: Not enough information. There's nothing wrong with what you posted so far. Maybe some other code damages the value of `price` after `scanf`. For example, if you overflow the `itemName` array it will spill into `price` and damage its value.

Comment: Please show the declaration and initialization of `new_node`.

Comment: Can you post the statement that is outputting as well?

Comment: What happens if you `scanf` into a plain-old `float`?  If that has the same problem, your issue probably isn't with the `struct`.

Comment: Suggest `scanf()` is working fine, but the "32" is being consumed by earlier code.

Comment: inb4 256 char null-terminated string copied into 'itemName'.

Comment: @AndreyT you are correct.  i did not provide enough, when i investigatd further, i see without scanning in the ID number, this works.  but when i scan in the ID number first, it's gone... i can't seem to understand what's going on :/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight provided

Comment: Too little data, but there's `new_node` and `newNode` in your shown code snippet, so these are not the same. Probably this is handled in the not-shown piece of code.

Comment: typo. sorry. you are too quick :) i fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input data gets "misaligned" with your `scanf` calls. The part that looks particularly suspicious is reading the book title: it is a string, so good chances are that the `ID` number gets consumed by `scanf` along with the proper title of the book.

Once this happens, using `%d` on `32.40` consumes `32` for an `ID`, leaving `.40` in the buffer. When `%f` comes along, it takes this input as a proper floating point number without triggering an error.

To address this issue you could introduce a special terminating character, say, `;`, for the title, and put it into the input as a marker. This would let you read the title using `%255[^;]` to read the title, stopping before reaching the `ID` portion of the input.